# Is "ne" used as a pronunciation for any character except 呢?

Tags: pinyin, names

I am wondering about the Pinyin syllable `ne` (specifically, `nè`), because it is the ending of the name of a friend of mine. We are searching for a Chinese character that accurately represents this sound -- `那` is too strong because it sounds like `na` and I am not sure if `呢` is really appropriate for a name.

Are there any characters appropriate for a name that have this sound `ne` or `nè`?

Comment: There's a name [哪吒](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nezha), but the tone of `哪` is 2nd tone, `né`.

Comment: https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=1&wdqb=ne4

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_into_Chinese_characters 中文译名

Comment: Is your friend's name spelled in pinyin?

Comment: Neville Chamberlain **内** 维尔·张伯伦  Benjamin Netanyahu 本雅明· **内** 塔尼亚胡，Jawaharlal Nehru 贾瓦哈拉尔· **尼** 赫鲁

Comment: @user6065 Thanks, in English Netanyahu and Nehru are pronounced with a long `ne` sound, I am looking for a schwa (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa, IPA ə) like your first example Neville. Interesting they also use 内 for that sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could reference the name **Zinedine，Zidane**, which has been translated as **齐内迪纳, 齐达内**.

So, you can use either 内 or 纳 to transliterate **ne**.